# Amazon EC2 EBS IO Count is high

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpbb, ubuntu-11.04, amazon-ebs

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 +Apache +Mysql +php on free micro tier of Amazon EC2, complete root is attached to EBS.. The db size of mysql is 700 MB.. but in just 45 hours of running the instance.. I/O count is 713,136... ??
I have installed phpbb on my website and it is getting around 4000 pageview/day. how can I optimize the I/O..

Comment: Start by finding out what part of your application or operating system is generating the IO.  It isn't possible for somebody else to offer specific advice without knowing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use APC (Alternate PHP Caching) so that there is no I/O request for cached pages.
If anybody else has better idea please post it.